ValidateIf() is not working as expected . Not Validating (NestJS)
I am using validateIf() to check if the paymentService is equal to some enum value defined in my code. But it does not validate and throws an error .

    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEnum(PAYMENT_SERVICE,{
        message:`Payment Service must be one of the valid values ${Object.values(PAYMENT_SERVICE)}`
    })
    paymentService: PAYMENT_SERVICE
    
    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsInt()
    @Transform(({ value }) => parseInt(value))
    amount: number

    @ApiProperty({ required: false })
    @ValidateIf((object) => object.paymentService == PAYMENT_SERVICE.STRIPE)
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    currency: string

    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsInt()
    @Transform(({ value }) => parseInt(value))
    qurandaziId: number
} 



export enum PAYMENT_SERVICE {
    STRIPE = 'STRIPE',
    JAZZCASH = 'JAZZCASH',
}


 


In currency field replace
@IsOptional()

with
@IsNotEmpty({ message: 'currency_not_empty' })


It is important the order top-to-bottom of Validation Decorators. In this case, you place @IsOptional Validator below @ValidateIf.
That means, after the .payment service has the value you need in the condition, you add the optional validator for the property currency.
In addition, a string, can be also an empty string, like "". So, it is not a good practice to have the currency as string. It 'd be better if you also defined another Enum for the various cases of currencies.
Below is an example of the code I 've used for production, which is the same case as yours.
  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Required for input currency.', required: false, enum: CurrencyEnum }) 
  @ValidateIf(obj => obj.action === InputEnum.CURRENCY)
  @IsEnum(CurrencyEnum)
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'currency must not be empty when input is "currency"' })
  currency!: CurrencyEnum;

